# Where can a dependency be specified if not in Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I'm looking at the [`ring`](https://crates.io/crates/ring/0.16.20) crate. In its [Dependencies](https://crates.io/crates/ring/0.16.20/dependencies) tab I see there is a dependency to the [`web-sys`](https://crates.io/crates/web-sys) crate. But in `ring`'s [`Cargo.toml`](https://github.com/briansmith/ring/blob/main/Cargo.toml) I don't see `web-sys` mentioned anywhere. So where does that dependency come from?

Comment: It could be a indirect dependency, a dependency of a dependency of `ring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing apples to oranges. You're seeing the dependencies of version 0.16.20 and comparing that with the *current* `Cargo.toml` even when there are nearly two years of difference between them.

If you look at the repository at the 0.16.20 release, you'll see that `Cargo.toml` does have a web-sys dependency: https://github.com/briansmith/ring/tree/9cc0d45f4d8521f467bb3a621e74b1535e118188

Comment: Ah, yes. I thought I had checked the previous version as well, but apparently I was wrong. Thanks! But anyway, are there other places where a dependency could be specified?

Comment: No, I don't think so